# how can I use a returned list in python?

Tags: python

I want to illustrate the movement of a particle in python in a one dimensional space but I cannot use an arbitrary returned list

here what I've done:

```py
import random as rd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
def libreparcoursmoyen(x_0,pas):
    L=[x_0]
    x=x_0
    for k in range(pas):
        x=x+rd.choice(1,-1)
        L.append(x)
    return L 
plt.plot(L)
```

but I do get the following error : NameError: name 'L' is not defined

how can I write my code so that it gives me the plot at the end of it ?

Comment: You didn't actually call the function so there is no returned list to use.

Comment: thanks for the answers ! Ermolai your suggestion helped me but I want to code a program so that I decide the inital point and the step when I'm using it not in the code.

Comment: You defined your function: `def libreparcoursmoyen(x_0,pas)`. If you want to call it and get a list in return you need to supply values of `x_0` and `pas` in your function call..

Comment: "NameError: name 'L' is not defined" - yes, that will still happen even if you do call the function, because functions **return values, not names**. Please see the linked duplicate in order to understand how to use functions properly.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't call the function at all

```py
import random as rd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
def libreparcoursmoyen(x_0,pas):
    L=[x_0]
    x=x_0
    for k in range(pas):
        x=x+rd.choice(1,-1)
        L.append(x)
    return L
plt.plot(libreparcoursmoyen(<args>))
```

Don't forget to pass arguments to the function

Comment: now that I understood the problem I had with not calling the function, I have a problem with the undefined arguments I guess I have to " pass arguments to function" but I don't know what does it actually mean . thanks for the help NotEasy

Comment: "I guess I have to " pass arguments to function" but I don't know what does it actually mean " - in your own words, when you wrote `def libreparcoursmoyen(x_0,pas):`, exactly what do you think this means? Specifically, what do you think the `x_0,pas` part means? Inside the code, where it says e.g. `L=[x_0]` or `for k in range(pas):`, how do you think the function should know the values to use for `x_0` and `pas`?

Comment: More importantly: think clearly to how you found out **that there is such a thing** as a "function", or that you can write `def` in Python code and have it mean something. Go back there and **read everything else** that it tells you about functions. @AihamElofairi